# Redshift Table Invisible to Owner

Tags: sql, permissions, amazon-redshift, sql-grant

I'm creating a table with a superuser (admin), and trying to `GRANT ALL` and change the owner of a table.

I'm running the following statements in Redshift, where (non-superuser) `john` is a member of the `developers` group (and only a member of the `developers` group):

```
GRANT ALL ON users.addresses TO GROUP developers;
ALTER TABLE users.addresses OWNER TO john;
```

I've confirmed that user `john` has select/insert/delete/update permissions on `users.addresses`, and is the owner of the table.  I've also confirmed that user `john` has `USAGE` on the `users` schema.

However, when I log in as `john`, the table simply does not appear.  When I try a `SELECT * FROM users.addresses`, Redshift says that the table does not exist.

What am I missing here?  Is there an extra layer of permissions or security in Redshift that I'm not seeing?  I've looked through the documentation, but haven't had much luck so far.

Comment: How does pg_user  look like for the user john?

Comment: Maybe because you are granting access on table **users.addresses** but query uses table **users.permissions** ?

Comment: My mistake @EdgarsT. - amended so the SELECT query is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Because Redshift is saying that the table doesn't exist, that points towards the `CREATE TABLE` not being committed to the database when you're running it as a superuser account. If you disconnect as the superuser account and then reconnect and attempt to run the `SELECT` statement against the table, do you get the same error?

Try running an explicit `COMMIT` statement after you create the table, and then attempt querying it using the non-superuser account. If the client you are using is wrapping all query executions inside of a transaction block, it is possible that they aren't being committed prior to you connecting with the non-superuser account.

Also for reference, I ran the following queries with auto-commit enabled and was unable to replicate the issue you're describing:

```
-- Run as superuser account:
CREATE SCHEMA users;

CREATE TABLE users.addresses (
    user_id VARCHAR(8) ,
    user_address VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO users.addresses VALUES ('12345678', 'Address 1');

CREATE USER john WITH PASSWORD '********';

CREATE GROUP developers;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA users TO GROUP developers;

ALTER GROUP developers ADD USER john;

GRANT ALL ON users.addresses TO GROUP developers;

ALTER TABLE users.addresses OWNER TO john;

-- Run as non-superuser account 'john':
SELECT *
FROM users.addresses;

-- Result Set:
-- user_id  user_address
-- 12345678 Address 1
```